# Changing backgroundcolor of a table-cell based on its value

Tags: django, libreoffice, odt

I'm using this nice tool [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) to generate ODT-Files in my django-application. Is there a way to change the backgroundcolor of a table-cell based on its value?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in LibreOffice its easily found on the menu.

Format -> Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Which version of LibreOffice are you referring to?

Comment: @PareidoliaX I need this in an writer-document (odt) not in an calc-document. In writer I can't find "conditional formatting" under the menu Format. I'm using LibreOffice 4.0.3.3

Comment: Maybe this video helps: http://mindmapapp.blogspot.nl/2013/03/conditional-formatting-in-libreoffice-4.html

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a tag for the color in your django application and then have a post process LibreOffic Writer macro going through the tags and change the background color of the cells accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. However I don't know where to start. I already pass the right values in the cells of the table via [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html). How can I write a macro that works with django tags? How can I run the macro after that pod has created the odt?

Comment: You would need to add 'helper tags' like ##red in addition to the values of the cells. The macro then searches for the ##red tag, selects the cells and sets the background color accordingly. However I would check if pod does not allow to do that directly. Maybe you can add an example to the question.