# How to build an editable text document with its base content dynamically generated?

Tags: latex, pdf-generation, restructuredtext, libreoffice, desktop-publishing

I have a relational database (PostgreSQL 8.4) of around 3000 products proposed by a company. The database is used to display the products in the company’s website (running on a python 2.6 application).
My final goal is to build a PDF file in order to print a paper version of the products catalog and I would like to know what technology to use for that purpose.
The operation will have to be repeated once a year for every new catalog so I would like to automate the catalog generation but still give some flexibility because I won’t stay in the company forever and there is no technical person that will replace me after (small company, small budget).

Ideally, I would like to generate dynamically the structured content of the 3000 products in a text editor (like OpenOffice for example) for the following reasons:

- content is generated dynamically so no need to retype everything
- only the content structure is generated dynamically and not the styling so a non-technical user is able to customize styles.
- the document being editable, it is easy for a non-technical user to add pages in the catalog like a welcome page, a note page, the terms and conditions.
  In other words, text editors are great, I don’t want to reinvent the wheel but I don’t want a person to retype all data for the 3000 products.

Soutions first looked:

- I had a look at LaTeX but it seem that the data and the styling are mixed together in opposition to HTML and CSS which clearly separate content and styling which I find much more easy to use.
- I thought about using directly HTML and CSS but it might too technical.
- I also looked at a library allowing to generate PDF directly from python like ReportLab (http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/tutorial/product-catalogue/). This, however, does not allow to modify anything once the PDF is build and a little modification might required a technical person.

So if you have an idea for this kind of job then I would be very happy to get some tips about the right technologies. Thank you very much.

Comment: I wrote a script in R that executes the standard toolchain on an input .tex document (ie say pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex). One of the many arguments that the script takes, is a provision of a flat file, where each row is used to globally replace wildcard fields in the source document, producing a distinct pdf for each row in the table, so this could be used to create a 'pamphlet' for all products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## OpenDocument Format (ODF) approach

### Why:

- It is an open format, which is guarantee for long term solution, and it comes with no cost (small company, small budget).
- It separates content and style.
- There are mature free and open source software compatible with it: OpenOffice.org, LibreOffice. And these are easy to use for non-programmer users.

### How:

The ODF format is quite complex but some libraries already exist to help generating files, and there are some available in Python: [odfpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/odfpy), [lpod](https://github.com/lpod/lpod-python),[JODreports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/), [Apache odf toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791389/how-to-create-an-odt-file-programmatically-with-java), ...
And they seem to do the job!

[Simliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791389/how-to-create-an-odt-file-programmatically-with-java) but for Java

Comment: Etienne, maybe you can convert this answer to a wiki page (just tick the check box when you edit this question) and then people can add more explanations and links to other tools.

Comment: After playing with both LaTeX and OpenDocument Format (by using LibreOffice and odfpy), I consider that ODF is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

## Approach in LaTeX

### General

LaTeX does allow to separate content from styling, as it is a markup language (and feels pretty like HTML and CSS if you are coming from it).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language#TeX

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#Getting_LaTeX_to_process_multiple_files

> This way you can put all the formatting options in your base file and then input or include the files which contain the actual content of your work. This means that the important part of your working process, i.e. writing, is kept largely separate from formatting choices (which is one of the main reasons why LaTeX is so good for serious writing!) You will thus be dealing solely with text and very basic commands such as \section, \emph etc. Your document will be uncluttered and much easier to work with..

The commands `\input{filename}` and `\include{filename}` insert text files (with or without LaTex commands).

For more customization you would need own macro(s) to read the content files and style them accordingly.

Some resources on defining macros (I can´t provide the linked hyperlinks because of my reputation right now):

en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros

en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages

### One specific example

I´ve written a software documentation, the actual source code was stored in separate files. The `lstinputlisting` package reads the source code and outputs it in a "styled way".

```tex
\lstinputlisting[caption=My caption]{sourcefile.lang}
```

Comment: I clearly didn't looked enough at LaTeX, I will do so straight away. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [database publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_publishing). This can be done with a batch formatter (e.g. TeX or XSL-FO) or -- if you need don't want 100% automation -- with addons for DTP programs like InDesign and Quark.

Comment: I do not need full automation, only the products publishing is necessary. However, I will need free (in the sense of liberty) tools and file formats so I will not go with InDesign and Quark. I am trying so see if there are opensource equivalents, LibreOffice maybe?

Comment: @EtienneRouxel: I don't know of any database publishing products for open/libre office or scribus; you'll probably need to write them yourself (which shouldn't be too difficult).

Comment: What do you mean exactly? That I should write a publishing software or a little script that takes data from my database and generate a XML file in ODF (Open Document Format)? Or do you mean something else?
Sorry if the question is not clear, I am trying to understant the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

## Database publishing

Yes, as Martin Schroeder points out this is about *database publishing*. A recent similar [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987806/changing-backgroundcolor-of-a-table-cell-based-on-its-value) is about using the [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) tool to generate LibreOffice ODT files.

The *pod* approach uses Python. Python statements are in the ODF template file. You might use the approach with any scripting language.

LibreOffice Writer has as well a 'flat XML' file format. A database publishing batch process needs to replace certain place holders with XML code generated from the database.
This might be done by an interpreter which goes through your 'flat XML' file and looks for certain keywords or commands and then executes them.

**Advantage**
The advantage of this approach is that a general user can alter the report just by using LibreOffice. Insertion commands which are interpreted by your batch program may be easily placed at the right place. These command may have the form of a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_specific_language).

Comment: Do you know what are the benefits of this technique in comparison to using a python library that helps generating the OpenDocument file, like [ODFPy](http://mashupguide.net/1.0/html/ch17s04.xhtml) for example?

Comment: Contrariwise to LaTeX LibreOffic Writer is a general purpose text processing system people can easily learn. I have added a paragraph 'Advantage'. However the approach Martin Schroeder mentions is not all that difficult either if one is willing to deal with a batch text processing system as LaTeX is. For example you need to make sure that every opening curly bracket has a corresponding closing bracket.

Comment: I am afraid that my users are not willing to learn anything. They are the kind of person that formats the text manually while typing it instead of using styles. So I don't really imagine them learning something that appears like commands (LaTeX or else).